# SQL Server Management Studio always appends $ to table name when importing from Excel

Tags: excel, ssms

I've noticed that whenever I try to import data from an Excel file, the Server Management Studio importer will append a $ to the name. I'm not sure why this is, but it is awkward because then you end up with tables like `table$` instead of the `table` you want it imported to.

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to avoid it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This question would be a better fit on http://superuser.com.

Comment: @ScottCraner - You can VTC for that reason and if closed it will migrate automatically, I believe.